# Merge two associative arrays into one array for MongoDB Laravel 7

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, laravel-7

End goal:

- Get the old array (repository_data) and their subarrays.
- In the repository_data array, insert $newData array.
- Merge repository_data arrays with newData array!

I have a document on my MongoDB which I created (maybe it needs fixing?)

When I run a query the result is the following:

```
#attributes: array: 4[
  ▼"_id"=>MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId{
    #1292▶
  }"team_data"=>array: 2[
    ▼"team_id"=>"94""repository_data"=>array: 1[
      ▼0=>array: 4[
        ▼"repository_id"=>2"repository"=>"DataSomething""token"=>"notoken1""url"=>"nourl1"
      ]
    ]
  ]"updated_at"=>MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime{
    #1293▼+"milliseconds": "1614177748010"
  }"created_at"=>MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime{
    #1294▼+"milliseconds": "1614177748010"
  }
]
```

What I am interested are the values stored here:

> team_data['repository_data']

**What I want to do is to create a new MongoDB record which will have the same exact format but will the addition of another array inside "repository_data".**

Which on the first submission the data are:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "repository_id" => 2
    "repository" => "dataverse"
    "token" => "ssxc"
    "url" => "qwe3"
  ]
]
```

This is where my question comes into play:
-> How do I create an array which will house my new array AND the old one (a multidimensional array)?

Like merge them in one Large array that will contain associative arrays...

```
 -repository_data =>
--[0]RepoData => [Things...]
--[1]RepoData => [Same key things different values]
--[N]RepoData
```

I thought of going through the old array()
Array_merge is not the solution.

My new values are stored in the following array value:

```
        $newData = array(
            'repository_id' => $repositoryID,
            'repository' => $request->repository,
            'token' => $request->dataverse_token,
            'url' => $request->dataverse_url,
        );
```

I thought of this:

```
$newData = [
 "repository_id" => $repositoryID,
 "repository" => $request->repository,
 "token" => $request->dataverse_token,
 "url" => $request->dataverse_url,
  ];

 $oldData = $collection->team_data['repository_data'];

 $arrayPot = array();

  foreach ($oldData as $od) {
     $oldDataNew= $arrayPot + $od;
  }
```

Results in this:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "repository_id" => 2
    "repository" => "WiiVerse"
    "token" => "sample1"
    "url" => "sample1.com"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "repository_id" => 2
    "repository" => "WiiVerse"
    "token" => "sample2"
    "url" => "sample2.com"
  ]
]
```

Which is **wrong**, because one of the arrays became a sub array(s) on oldDataNew (meaning they belong to team_data['repository_data']**[0]**).

When requesting team_data['repository_data'] I want the following output:

```
array: 5[
  ▼0=>array: 4[
   "repository_id"=>2"repository"=>"wii""token"=>"SomethingElse""url"=>"SE1"
  ▼1=>array: 4[
"repository_id"=>2"repository"=>"wii""token"=>"ssxc""url"=>"SE1"
]
```

This will merge two arrays together (in theory?) BUT the data of the second variable will be only stored:

```
dd(array(($newData)+($oldDataNew)));
```

This does work (somewhat) as shown on the code above:

```
dd($oldDataNew[]=array(($newData),($oldDataNew)));
```

**BUT** the problem is that when the user tries to input another value (on submitting the form) the same code is executed. Every old value is stored in one big array and the new value will NOT be inserted in that array and that's an issue. It cause sub sub sub sub arrays...

Behold the third insert (notice how the two old arrays are now subarrays)

```
0 => array:5 [▼
      "repository_id" => 2
      "repository" => "dataverse"
      "token" => "kkkkk"
      "url" => "llll"
      0 => array:2 [▼
        0 => array:4 [▼
          "repository_id" => 2
          "repository" => "dataverse"
          "token" => "5467"
          "url" => "rtf"
        ]
        1 => array:4 [▼
          "repository_id" => 2
          "repository" => "dataverse"
          "token" => "kkkkk"
          "url" => "llll"
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

Doing the following:

```
dd($submissionData[]=$oldDataNew+$newData);
```

Results in:

```
    0 => array:4 [▼
      "repository_id" => 2
      "repository" => "dataverse"
      "token" => "5467"
      "url" => "rtf"
    ]
```

As you can see, one array is lost and only one is stored. Why? Because they hold the same key values?

The closer (I think) I came to combine those arrays (the old ones and the new one) is through this:

```
$batman = $oldData  + $newData;
```

$oldData has the following (for example) values:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "repository_id" => 2
    "repository" => "dataverse"
    "token" => "123sdws"
    "url" => "123"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "repository_id" => 2
    "repository" => "dataverse"
    "token" => "fff"
    "url" => "vvv"
  ]
]
```

$oldData  + $newData will result in:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "repository_id" => 2
    "repository" => "dataverse"
    "token" => "123sdws"
    "url" => "123"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "repository_id" => 2
    "repository" => "dataverse"
    "token" => "fff"
    "url" => "vvv"
  ]
]
```

Running the following:

```
foreach (($newData) as $nd){
   $oldData= $oldData+ ($nd);
}
```

will result in:

```
array:6 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "repository_id" => 2
    "repository" => "dataverse"
    "token" => "123sdws"
    "url" => "123"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "repository_id" => 2
    "repository" => "dataverse"
    "token" => "fff"
    "url" => "vvv"
  ]
  "repository_id" => 2
  "repository" => "dataverse"
  "token" => "kkkk"
  "url" => "llll"
]
```

Comment: Is this the minimal version of your [mcve]?

Comment: I think I am somewhere between Minimal and Reproducible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was naive:

```
foreach (($newData) as $nd) {
   $arrayPot = array_merge($oldData, array($nd));
 }
```

Where $newData is:

```
            $newData = array([
                "repository_id" => $repositoryID,
                "repository" => $request->repository,
                "token" => $request->dataverse_token,
                "url" => $request->dataverse_url,
            ]);
```

and $oldData holds the values for all the previous records for repository_data

My loop results in the following:

```
  "repository_data" => array:4 [▼
        0 => array:4 [▼
          "repository_id" => 2
          "repository" => "dataverse"
          "token" => "123sdws"
          "url" => "123"
        ]
        1 => array:4 [▼
          "repository_id" => 2
          "repository" => "dataverse"
          "token" => "kkkk"
          "url" => "3333"
        ]
        2 => array:4 [▼
          "repository_id" => 2
          "repository" => "dataverse"
          "token" => "4444"
          "url" => "5555555555"
        ]
        3 => array:4 [▼
          "repository_id" => 2
          "repository" => "dataverse"
          "token" => "1111"
          "url" => "22333"
        ]
      ]
```

I still don't understand that $newData must be an array **and then again** declare it as an array inside my foreach loop

Comment: Is this an answer or is this a continuation of your quest for support?

Comment: No it is the actual solution. Still can't understand why $newData has to be an array